# regex for firstname and lastname

Tags: javascript, regex

am validating firstname and lastname fields. and below is the requirement

- block special characters
- atleast one alphabet
- alphanumeric allowed

am using this regex :

firstNamenoSpecialChar:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/
```

i need to add one more condition :  length should be min 2 and max 25

please help.

Comment: I hope you only use that for a game and not in real world... There are **many** real firstnames and lastnames which you would reject.

Comment: What if my name is 精武? :(

Comment: German Names like "Müller" woud be blocked?

Comment: of the special chars main requirement is to block quote in these fields as they get passed to some other user creation tools which break on seeing single quote. hence included "special chars" as we need to block those visible special chars on board..  thanks...

Comment: USA Citizens have Numbers in their names?

Comment: @Nano i can see some records having numbers (may be its of internal users / perf-test dummy user created)  am ok if u ignore number and share working copy of edited expression.

Comment: @user1603828 just first and lastnames or also middlenames?

Comment: including middlenames...  i have only 2 fields in ui fname, lname.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will do it: `^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.{2,25}$)[\w ]+$`
It uses a series of positive lookaheads to check the conditions before actually consuming the valid characters.

Here's the breakdown:

`(?=.*[A-Za-z])` requires at least one letter

`(?=.{2,25}$)` requires between 2 and 25 characters for the whole string

`[\w ]+` allows only letters, digits, underscores, and spaces (I'm not sure why you want underscores, though)

Comment: also would be help full if u got some good links to read on this topic... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to create a function that would look like :

```
function validateName(strName){
    var nameValide = true;
    if(strName.length<2){ nameValide = false; }
    if(strName.length>25){ nameValide = false; }
    // validate that only the valide caracter are in the string
    if(strName.replace(/a-Z/g,'') != ''){ namValide= false;} 
    return nameValide;
}
```

Comment: also i feel u really deserve those badges and reputation as atleast u made some attempt..